# MySQL on MACOS Sierra secure-file-priv setting

Tags: mysql, configuration, mac-os-x

I cannot find where to set `secure-file-priv`. I get this message:

> 1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

when running this statement:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, data_type FROM tabledefs INTO  OUTFILE  'xpeter'
```

If I remove `OUTFILE 'xpeter'`  it works.  `OUTFILE '/tmp/xpeter` does not work either.

I tried to add `--secure-file-priv="/tmp"` , no change. Variable stays as NULL:

```
 $bindir/mysqld_safe --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" --secure-file-priv="/tmp"    $other_args >/dev/null &  

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep secure-file
  --secure-file-priv=name 
secure-file-priv                                             NULL
```

There is no `my.cnf` file.  I run through whole filesystem, looking for any `*.cnf` file.  Could not find any other than: `./mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/data/auto.cnf` and `./mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/support-files/my-default.cnf`.  The line `$bindir/mysqld...`  is in `support-files/my-default.cnf`.

I rerun the query without `OUTFILE 'xpeter'`,  query OK, no messages in log files except `apache2 log`.  Then I run

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, data_type INTO  OUTFILE  'xpeter' FROM tabledefs
```

no errors in  logfiles, only in phpmyadmin (where I run the query statement from, logged in as root): same message as before.

I tried the `etc/my.cnf` and also:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
   <string>--secure-file-priv=/mysql_exp</string>
        </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>  <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In both cases after reboot I was still not allowed to write a file.

I did not change the folder owner. If I add `--secure-file-priv=/mysql_exp` to Daemons and reboot MySQL does not run at all.

Comment: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366143,376017

Answer (score 5):

on mac os x startup parameters of mysql You can change by edit .plist file

location:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons
com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Use Xcode or for example BBEdit, and add line in section ProgramArguments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>600</integer>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
        <string>--user=_mysql</string>
        <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
        <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
        <string>--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err</string>
        <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
        <string>--secure-file-priv=/mysql_exp</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

restart MySQL and check:

```
mysql> show variables like 'secure%';
+------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name    | Value       |
+------------------+-------------+
| secure_auth      | ON          |
| secure_file_priv | /mysql_exp/ |
+------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Add:**

You can achieve same result if will create my.cnf file straight in /etc/

```
sudo nano /etc/my.cnf
```

You can copy example file from

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/
```

**just notes about comments** - "copy/past" it's not a way, even on Your Mac You really do not need file import/export at all
just use normal tools like:

- MySQL Workbench
- Navicat for MySQL
- JetBrain IDE (most of them have database module)
- DBVisualizer

any of them can help You:

- export result of query into different format - csv, delimited file, json, xls
- Import popular format of files direct into table, with mapping columns to datatypes

manual file level import/export could be useful in production environment where You need automate processes, but also for now it is more backup way, primary and proper - ETL scripts and tools.

Comment: 1) as a note `--secure-file-priv=/mysql_exp` means that only the  _/mysql_exp_ directoy will be read/written when export and import operations.  
2) For more flexibility, leave it empty `--secure-file-priv=`.  
3) Using xcode I am not able to edit the file as it complains about permissions, what I did is using terminal+sudo I copied it to another dir, edited and the recopied it to the original location (always store an unchanged copy somewhere in case of a problem).

Comment: I do not have the `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` file in LaunchDaemons.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file /etc/my.cnf and add the following lines

```
[mysqld_safe]
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv="/Users/abc/"
```

and restart

Comment: This did not work for me (replacing "abc" with my username").

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Christia, it should be a valid directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "[mysqld]\nsecure_file_priv\t\t= ''\n" | sudo tee /etc/my.cnf
```

And then restart mysql. If brew was used to install the mysql run the following command:

```
brew services restart mysql
```

Comment: `sudo tee /etc/my.cnf` -- wouldn't that overwrite the entire configuration file? Seems a bit dangerous to me. Besides, it disables file security altogether, when you'd probably want to limit it to a certain directory only.

Comment: Fair enough. In my case I was interested in getting a csv export of a mysql dump created by someone else. So installing a fresh mysql introduced the `secure_file_priv` constraint and `/etc/my.cnf` didn't exist. So there was nothing to overwrite and I didn't care where to save the export so that oneliner worked for me well. But I agree that I didn't think about overwritting the config file and the dump location might be inappropriate in some cases.